# How to add two integer values as year and month to a date variable?

Tags: java, sql, date, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0 beta.

I have 2 integers with values obtained from a database table.

```
int year, month;
try{
      string sql = "select * from item where item_id = i001";
      pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs = pst.executeQuery();

      rs.next();
      year = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("warr_years"));
      month = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("warr_months"));

}
catch(SQLException e){
}
```

And I have a String variable which holds the current date.

```
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        String d = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Now I need to add the years and months to the date. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); and add to your year and month

Comment: Java 8 has tremendously improved such handling, borrowing from JODA. With new classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Calender` to do that.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
Date newDate = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `year` format is off. It's "yyyy" not "YYYY". Next, you can use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and something like

```
int year = 10;
int month = 2;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, year);  // <-- add year years to the Calendar.
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);// <-- add month months to the Calendar.
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); // <-- display the result
```

The above code outputs (on today, the 27th of August 2014) -

```
2024-10-27
```